# Find layerattribute at certain point

Tags: leaflet, spatial-query, function

I am trying to find the closest road segment to a point that I have and return an attribute from the closest segment to the given points. How should I do that? Any suggestions?

Can i use a marker and then show attribute-data from another layer in the markers popup?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not a trivial thing to do just with Leaflet+Javascript.

The quickest thing that comes to my mind is using [TurfJS](http://turfjs.org/) to compute the [distance](http://turfjs.org/docs/#distance) between the point and a [point on that line](http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointonline), for all your line geometries (iterating over them), and keep a reference to the feature using the closest geometry.

To put it [all together like in this gist](https://github.com/rowanwins/turf-nearestPointToLine/blob/master/index.js):

```
for(i = 0; i < featureCollection.features.length; i++){
    var closestPoint = pointOnLine(linestring, featureCollection.features[i]);
    var distance = distanceCalc(featureCollection.features[i], closestPoint, units);

    if(distance < closestDistance || closestDistance === 0){
        closestFeature = closestPoint;
        closestDistance = distance;
    }
}
```

This might be computationally expensive specially in those cases where you have lots of line segments around. If that's the case, use [rbush](https://github.com/mourner/rbush) to index the bboxes of your lines, and use a [k-nearest-neighbour query](https://github.com/mourner/rbush-knn) to cull the amount of lines to check.

---

Another approach would be to generate a [Voronoi diagram based on line segments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104631/create-voronoi-diagram-from-line-segments) beforehand (which is computationally expensive), index the bboxes of the areas, and do point-in-polygon queries (which are computationally cheaper than finding the closest point in a line segment).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently for returning the closest street address to my points of interest within ESRI ArcMap
The process i used was to use the 'Near' tool (Analysis Tools/Proximity/Near).
ESRI help here - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm

Once you run this tool, it will add new fields to your input feature including a field called 'NEAR_FID". This is the ObjectID of the nearest attribute in the near feature you selected (in your case, the objectID of the closest road segment).

You can then do a table join to your roads database based on NEAR_FID in your points layer and OBJECTID in your roads layer. The joined table will display the nearest road name, and you can export this join in to a new feature class, or use the field calculator to update existing fields in your attribute table with road names