# Geospatial algorithm to create area midwayboundaries from lines?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find out if there is any existing geospatial algorithm (in any open Open Source Geospatial software) that would allow to use a network of lines as a start point and expand those in such a way that I can create new area boundaries for each of the lines "coverage area". What I mean with that is if one could "buffer" the lines out in such a way to create boundaries where any potential buffers would meet at the middle way point between the lines so that in the end I could have an area within that is the starting line. On example could look like this (5 hand drawn lines in red and corresponding colored areas that I would want to create). Note that is exact but to communicate the idea) see http://terra5.terragis.net/sites/html/aeras_for_lines%20copy.png

It's kind of similar to Thiessen polygons but for lines instead of points...

One preference would be if there was something that could be used programmatically on large data sets ...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348154/120129 can help, just make sure you set the right number of points...